# Once I successfully connect to a room, how do I place the video player on the page?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm using plain old javascript, so no npm packages or webpack please. I've very close to having this work but missing one last step.

```
  var connectOptions = {
  accessToken: 'eyJhb...',
  roomName: 'test127',
           audio: true,
           video: { width: 640 },
          _useTwilioConnection: true
  };
```

With this `connectOptions` (it has a valid jwt) I'm able to connect like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Twilio.Video.connect(connectOptions.accessToken, connectOptions).then(function(room) {
    console.log('Connected to Room "%s"', room.name);
          console.log(room);
      //var player = new Twilio.Video.Player('player-container');
      //var t = player.load(room.sid);
      //player.play();

  }, function(error) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to Room', error);
  });
});
```

And I see the success "Connected to Room" message and the green light of my camera comes on! I've tried placing:

```
  <div id="player-container"></div>
   <video id="videoinput" autoplay></video>
```

But I can't seem to find the right next step to get the video player on the screen.

I'm using:

```
  <script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.14.0/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

works with:

```
var v123 = document.getElementById("v123");
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            var theTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            v123.srcObject = new MediaStream([theTrack]);
            v123.play();
          });
```

And:

```
   <video style="width: 600px; height: 600px;" id="v123" autoplay playsinline style="opacity: 0"></video>
```

after you have done:

```
  var connectOptions = {
  audio: { deviceId: { exact: aid } },
  video: { width: 640, deviceId: { exact: vid } },
          accessToken: 'jwt',
          roomName: 'room123',
          _useTwilioConnection: true
  };
```

where aid and vid come from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

EDIT: I ended up using all of https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/2734a083a8a2b3e77f1436d7cee8bc9ec18a94f0/quickstart/src/joinroom.js

and https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/2734a083a8a2b3e77f1436d7cee8bc9ec18a94f0/quickstart/public/index.html

to get this working. There a lot more complexity to getting two parties to join.